# how to extend array in parent class in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, class, oop

how to extend array in parent class in PHP?

I have something like this

```
class ParentClass {
    $this->player = array(
        'class' => array(
            'basic' => array(
                'name'      => $data['name'],
                'image'     => $data['img']
            )
        )
    );
}
```

how to extend $this->player array without erasing data in parent class with this data

```
class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    $this->player => array(
        'class' => array(
            'loadout'   => array(
                'primary'   => array(
                    'name'      => $data1['name'],
                    'type'      => $data1['type']
                )
            )
        )
    );
}
```

so the output will be

```
    (
        'class' => array(
            'basic' => array(
                'name'      => $data['name'],
                'image'     => $data['img']
            ),
            'loadout'   => array(
                'primary'   => array(
                    'name'      => $data1['name'],
                    'type'      => $data1['type']
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

I have tried this

```
class ParentClass {
    public $player;

    public function __construct($class) {
        $this->player = array(
            'class' => array(
                'basic' => array(
                    'name'      => $data['name'],
                    'image'     => $data['img']
                )
            )
        );
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    public function __construct($class) {

        parent::__construct($class);

        $this->player['class'] = array(
            'loadout'   => array(
                'primary'   => array(
                    'name'      => $data1['name'],
                    'type'      => $data1['type']
                )
            )
        );
    }

    public function getData() {
        return $this->player;
    }
}
```

but it only prints

```
    (
        'class' => array(
            'loadout'   => array(
                'primary'   => array(
                    'name'      => $data1['name'],
                    'type'      => $data1['type']
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your construct should look like this:

```
public function __construct($class) {

    parent::__construct($class);

    $this->player['class']['loadout'] = 
       array(
           'primary'   => array(
               'name'      => $data1['name'],
               'type'      => $data1['type']
            )
      );

}
```

Your code before overrode `class` with a new array. This code sets `loadout` of the array `class` to the new array.

Comment: You can make this more general by using `array_merge_recursive( $this->player, array('class'=>array('basic'=> ....)))`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol , I will halt my array_merge answer now and will +1 your answer :D

Comment: @wumm why didn't I think of that. That worked like a charm. Thanks a lot